# Android detect headset plugin through USB port

Tags: android, plugins, usb, headset

There is a new technology of headset that soon will be popular with more devices.

Devices has a type-C jack only without 3.5MM jack (Aux), and I would like to detect a plugin connection for listen music.
The regular way to detect Aux connection is

> ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG

Please help me find a solution for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: what makes you believe the `Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` doesn't work with USB-C headsets?