# USB headset detection in android

Tags: android, usb, headset

with the extinct of 3.5 audio headphone jack,How would one determine the plug-in or unplug activity of USB type C headset?

Traditional intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG state always returns '0' irrespective of USB headset state.

This query been raised earlier as well 
[Android detect headset plugin through USB port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498831/android-detect-headset-plugin-through-usb-port) but there is no solution mentioned.

Could someone please guide?

Comment: Also having the same problem. Any update on how to some this